# AS3 array visible false

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, visible, flash-cs5.5

i want to ask about this script

```
var dragbener:Array = new Array (dragmc, draglagi);    
this.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, masukframe)

    function masukframe(e:Event):void {

     if(dragmc.visible == false && draglagi.visible == false){
        //next2.visible=true;
        gotoAndStop(5);
          }
        }
```

but if i play that script the output is

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _2_fla::MainTimeline/masukframe()[_2_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:80]
```

and if i add the movieclip "dragmc" and "draglagi" in frame(5) there is no error.

what should i do if i want to go frame 5 when the movieclip dragmc and movieclip draglagi visible is false without add the movclip dragmc and draglagi in frame 5??

Comment: If you want to access dragmc and draglagi in each frame(as you code it) then you have to available those in every frame.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this'll fix it, but I'm fairly certain that you have to reference the array to access the elements (e.g. dragbener[1] instead of dragmc).

EDIT: Ah, snap. Forgot that you have to actually add the objects on the stage using `addChild();`

Comment: mmm how can i do that??
addchild(dragmc)??
@David

Comment: @IntanMega Normally, you just do `addChild(dragbener[1])` in your main method or, in this case, within `masukframe()`.

Comment: @IntanMega Haha, crud, sorry. You're supposed to add it where you defined your variables. Forgot that you're doing this on a timeline.

Comment: i try to add 'addChild(dragbener[1])' in my timeline..but when i remove dragmc in nextframe the error appears again. what should i do?

Comment: @IntanMega Do `trace(dragmc)` before you remove it and tell me what comes up.

Comment: 'Parameter child must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
 at _2_fla::MainTimeline/masukframe()[_2_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:73]'

myscript like this

'if(addChild(dragbener[1]).visible == false && addChild(dragbener[2])){
 trace(dragmc);
 gotoAndStop(5);'

Comment: @IntanMega You're not supposed to reference `addChild(dragbener[1])`. It's a function that adds the object onto the stage.

Comment: so how should I write it on stage?i'm a newbie in flash AS3 so i dont know how to do that..

Comment: @IntanMega Just out of curiosity, why did you make an array in the first place?

Comment: bcoz in the next frame the number of movieclip to drag will increase..so i think it will be easier and simple if i make an array

Comment: @IntanMega I think it's best if you learn how to use `addEventListener()`. Also, learn how to code outside of the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have those movieclips on the stage if you want to reference them, other options are have them called with `addChild();` but if you want to do it simply, put the movieclips on frame 5 and declare them invisible like so

```
dragmc.visible = false;
draglagi.visible = false;
```

Comment: actually i also use a simply method like that..but I want the other way, how to apply addchild()?
@Guram

Comment: this tutorial could be usefull as I learned adding movieclips on stage from here 
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist/